# C++: Copy object data in member function of base class

Tags: c++, oop

Suppose I have two classes A, and B. B is derived from A. A has no data members, however B has two integer members.

If I define a method in class A, like the following:

```
void CopyFrom( const A* other )
{
    *this = *other;
}
```

And call it in the child class, will the integer data member get copied?

Comment: I think they won't be copied, but I'd like to hear a correct answer as well.

Answer (score 7):

No.  This is known as the [*slicing problem*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c).

This is true even if you overload `operator=` in both `A` and `B`: `*this = *other` will only ever resolve to `A::operator=(const A&)` or `B::operator=(const A&)` being called.

Comment: @AtoMerZ: It depends on what you're trying to do.  If you ever get into a situation where you have an `A *` that's pointing to a `B`, and you want to `CopyFrom` another `B`, then you're probably doing something wrong!

Comment: @AtoMerZ: [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c/274977#274977) to the linked question gives the best solution.

Answer (score 3):

No. `this` doesn't have any space for members of child class. So the members of the Derived class will just get sliced of. This problem is called `Object Slicing`.

**How to solve it?**
***Prevention is better than cure!***

Dont introduce your code to a situation where `Object Slicing` occurs.
If you are facing the problem of `Object Slicing` you have a poorly architected/designed software program. Unless, ofcourse you are sacrificing good OOP design in favor of expediency.